# 500 (Internal Server Error) on jQuery POST

Tags: php, jquery, http-post

am sending a POST request with the jQuery lib to a PHP script, you'll find the scripts below. I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error as result, does someone know how to fix it?

**How I send the form:**

```
    $.post(
        "post.php",
        $( "#form" ).serialize()
    ).done(function( data ){
            generateFinishPage( data.link );
    });
```

**My post.php**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    $pdo = new PDO('...');
    
    $error = Array();

    if(empty($_POST['link']))
        $error [] = 'Er is geen link geselecteerd!';
        
    if(empty($_POST['sitename']))
        $error [] = 'Er is geen domein geselecteerd!';
        
    if(empty($_POST['image']))
        $error [] = 'Er is geen image geselecteerd!';
        
    $selectQuery = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM trolls WHERE url_text="' . $_POST['url'] . '" AND url_domein="' . $_POST["sitename"] . '"');
    if($selectQuery->rowCount() == 1)
        $error [] = 'Dezelfde link bestaat al!';
        
    if(count($error) == 0){
        $query = $pdo->query('INSERT INTO trolls (created_time, swf_theme, url_text, url_domain, creator_ip, creator_name, creator_text, creator_email) 
            VALUES (:created_time, :swf_theme, :url_text, :url_domain, :creator_ip, :creator_name, :creator_text, :creator_email)');
        $query->execute(
            array(
                ':created_time'     =>  date('d-m-o'),
                ':swf_theme'            =>  $_POST['image'] . ".swf",
                ':url_text'             =>  explode('/', $_POST['url'])[1],
                'url_domain'            =>  explode('/', explode(".", $_POST['url'])[1])[0],
                ':creator_ip'           =>  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                ':creator_name' =>  $_POST['creator_name'],
                ':creator_text'     =>  $_POST['creator_text'],
                ':creator_email'    =>  $_POST['creator_email']
            )
        );
        echo json_encode(array("link" => $_POST['url']));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("link" => array($error));
    }
    
    $pdo = null;
```

The form data that is sent:

> sitename:lnstagram.nl
>
> link:test
>
> image:anne
>
> creator_name:test
>
> creator_email:test@test.nl
>
> creator_text:test

[image: Form Data]

Thanks!

Comment: And what do the server logs say?

Comment: @user3584460 it's on a shared hosting, where do I find them?

Comment: Depending on the type of hosting/company. It is very unlikely not to have access to them though, so you can ask the support if you can't find them in your control panel.

Comment: check your select query.... is that "url_domein" or "url_domain"

Comment: @IndraKumarS You are right! I changed it thank you! But I am still getting a 500 error and a blanc page :s

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);  Add these two lines on top of your script  in your post.php and post your error here

Comment: @IndraKumarS They are already in my code, still getting a blanc page.

Comment: Whether it returns immediately or after 2mins

Comment: @IndraKumarS immediately

Comment: It means the problem is with the code

Comment: @IndraKumarS undifined index #fp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79267/discussion-between-indra-kumar-s-and-devniels).

Answer (score 2):

check your select query.... is that "url_domein" or "url_domain"?

What are you trying to do in your insert method?

I couldnt see any prepared statements But you have called execute method?

```
 $query->execute(
        array(
            ':created_time'     =>  date('d-m-o'),
            ':swf_theme'            =>  $_POST['image'] . ".swf",
            ':url_text'             =>  explode('/', $_POST['url'])[1],
            'url_domain'            =>  explode('/', explode(".", $_POST['url'])[1])[0],
            ':creator_ip'           =>  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            ':creator_name' =>  $_POST['creator_name'],
            ':creator_text'     =>  $_POST['creator_text'],
            ':creator_email'    =>  $_POST['creator_email']
        )
    );
```

Try to change the query like this... use prepare

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO trolls (created_time, swf_theme, url_text, url_domain, creator_ip, creator_name, creator_text, creator_email) 
        VALUES (:created_time, :swf_theme, :url_text, :url_domain, :creator_ip, :creator_name, :creator_text, :creator_email)');
```

Use try catch block for query to know where is the error

```
try {
       // query here
       } catch (PDOException $pe) {
          die("Error:" . $pe->getMessage());
      }
```

Comment: Thank you totally watched over it! I changed it, and also changed the url_domein into url_domain in the select query. Still getting a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Access your post.php directly and u will found the real error. And dont forget to show error in top of yor post.php

`error_reporting(E_ALL); nullini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: I am getting a blanc page if I try this, sorry forgot to tell that!

Comment: Strange. I canot cek your pdo query to make sure your script work beside the pdo queary give after if(count($error) == 0){ echo "query"; and command the query any inside it. I suggest to pdo exception class http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php